# Push specific commit a remote branch

Tags: git

I set up a local branch which tracks `remote/mainline` and made some changes to this local branch.

Besides `git push` to push the changes to `remote/mainline`, could I also push these changes to `remote/mainline2` without setting additional local branch tracking `remote/mainline2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can push to any branch you want

To push HEAD

```
git push origin HEAD:MY_FUN_NEW_BRANCH
```

To push a specific branch

```
git push origin mainline:mainline2
```

Answer (score 1):

If your local branch name is `mainline`:

```
git push remote mainline:mainline2
```

This is an explicit push which indicates the local source branch and the remote targeted one. It creates the remote branch if the one does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `git push origin [branchNameHere]` or `ggpush` if you use ohmyzsh (does the same thing)

Or if you want to continue to push to that branch and not need to go `ggpush`, just do `git branch -u [branch]` [--set-upstream works too]